# Long query: Does anyone know what this error is all about?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7

Currently, I am doing a query to a sql server database which has 6 million records.

A date range is specified in the query in order to filter the result. When the date range is short, i.e. 2 hours, the application displays the result with no problems.

But if the date range is a bit longer, i.e. a week, the application displays the following errors:

[image]

[image]

Finally, after I have accepted the two previous errors, and I click in any other section of the application I get the following error:

[image]

Strangely, this behaviour only happens in the live server (running on iis7), whereas in the localhost (casini) the applications displays the query results regardless the data range value.

Any thoughts on how to get around the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From `Sys.WebForms`, I guess you're using ASP.NET classic forms.  Consider logging the error server side.  `Application_Error` in `Global.asax` is a good place to log site-wide exceptions.

Comment: @Andomar I am already doing that. I'm logging errors in the database and in the event viewer. However, it seems like the error does not get there as no record is inserted into this two error logs

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, read following article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397479%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> When an error occurs on the server while the request is being processed, an error response is returned to the browser and a PageRequestManagerServerErrorExceptionobject is created by using the Error.create function. To customize error handling and to display more information about the server error, handle the AsyncPostBackError event and use the AsyncPostBackErrorMessage and AllowCustomErrorsRedirect properties. For an example of how to provide custom error handling during partial-page updates, see Customizing Error Handling for ASP.NET UpdatePanel Controls.

For second problem, may be you can get solution [here](http://vahidh.wordpress.com/tag/the-proxy-server-received-an-invalid-response-from-an-upstream-server/)

> Solution: Our web server could not resolve the URL of the back-end website. We needed to add a hosts file entry on our server to resolve the issue.